# How to download multiple objects from IBM Cloud Object Storage?

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

I am trying to use IBM Cloud Object Storage to store images uploaded to my site by users. I have this functionality working just fine.

However, based on the documentation here ([link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/api-reference/api-reference-objects.html#download-an-object)) it appears as though only one object can be downloaded from a bucket at a time.

Is there any way a list of objects could all be downloaded from the bucket? Is there a different approach to requesting multiple objects from a COS bucket?

Answer (score 1):

Via the REST API, no, you can only download a single object at a time.  But most tools (like the AWS CLI, or Minio Client) allow downloading all objects that share a prefix (eg `foo/bar` and `foo/bas`).  The IBM forks of the S3 libraries also are now integrated with Aspera, and can transfer large directories all at once. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am querying a db to get a list of objects that the front end requires. I am then trying to download these objects from the COS. However, I don't want to make separate requests for each object. I really just need a way to download these multiple objects at one go (all in the same bucket)

Answer (score 0):

According to S3 spec (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html), you can only download one object at a time.

Answer (score 0):

There are various [tools](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/moving-data-from-cos-to-file-or-block-storage/) which may help to download multiple objects at a time from COS. I used [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-windows.html) tool to download and upload the objects from/to COS.

So install aws-cli tool and configure it by supplying `access_key_id` and `secret_access_key` [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-aws-cli#aws-cli-config).

**Recursively copying S3 objects to a local directory:** When passed with the parameter `--recursive`, the following cp command recursively copies all objects under a specified prefix and bucket to a specified directory.

```
C:\Users\Shashank>aws s3 cp s3://yourBucketName . --recursive
```

for example:

```
C:\Users\Shashank>aws --endpoint-url http://s3.us-east.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud s3 cp s3://yourBucketName  D:\s3\  --recursive
```

In my case having endpoint based on us-east region and I am copying objects into D:\s3 directory.

**Recursively copying local files to S3:** When passed with the parameter --recursive, the following cp command recursively copies all files under a specified directory to a specified bucket.

```
C:\Users\Shashank>aws s3 cp myDir s3://yourBucketName/ --recursive
```

for example:

```
C:\Users\Shashank>aws --endpoint-url http://s3.us-east.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud s3 cp D:\s3 s3://yourBucketName/ --recursive
```

I am copying objects from D:\s3 directory to COS.

For more reference, you can see the link [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html).

I hope it works for you.